# How to calculate Photoshop letter spacing in css px or rem?

Tags: css, sass, photoshop

Anyone have any idea to how to calculate photoshop letter spacing in css px or rem.
Example: I have 140 letter spacing in photoshop.
Now, what should be this on CSS?
Or is there any way to do this with sass?

Comment: Honestly, I usually just test the hell out of it, make sure my container-widths & font-size match the design-comp/psd _exactly_ and pay close attention to the words that the new-lines start on. .01em is a good place to start.

Comment: @admcfajn I do agree with you but as we work for client & they test their website to px to px. And in that case, I don't have time to calculate or experiment every time.

Comment: Another technique I often use for precision front-end work is to find the percentage... Say you've got font-size: 50px, letter-spacing 3px. 3/50 = 0.06. What units are your psd using? Are you asking how to export css from photoshop? Sketch is a much better program for that. It goes a lot quicker that you might think. You don't have to test every word, How many design elements does the psd have? Good design repeats, so you can probably find a baseline for each of the styles and fine-tune it during QA if needed. Are you using a pre-compiler? Throwing some functions at it might help.

Comment: @HardenRahul You might as well teach your client that PixelPerfect™ Webdesign is not what they want. https://www.brettdev.com/exactly-pixel-perfect-design/

Answer (score 15):

Dividing the value in Photoshop by 1000 and setting that result in `em` gives pixel-perfect results.

For example, let's say in Photoshop you have a letter spacing of 50, the resulting css would be `letter-spacing: 0.05em`.

Create a simple function to help you do the math everytime:

```
@function letter-spacing($ps-value) {
    @return ($ps-value / 1000) * 1em
}
```

Comment: might be you are right and I also tried your code but as close as I found that it's not that exact. As it visual in photoshop.

But All the way thanks for the effort.

Comment: @HardenRahul it is expected to be not exact, but not because of Steve's answer (he is completely correct), but instead because of font rendering differences between Photoshop and browsers.

Comment: @flying that means the answer is not 100% exact as it should be.

Comment: More generally, that means there is no 100% exact answer.